# Frame with only crosses in two opposite corners

Tags: formatting, framed

Is there one package to produce frames looking like the one above in the following ASCII example ? **I don't want dashed lines.**

```
                                              |
                                          ----+--
      Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, ...  |
      Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, ...  |
      Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, ...
      Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, ...
   |  Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, ...
   |  Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, ...
 --+----
   |
```

**PRECISION :** I'm looking for something working like standard frames for paragraphs.

Comment: I believe that the `geometry` package has a `showcrop` option.  There is also a `crop` pacakge.

Comment: Maybe TikZ ?  :P

Comment: Could you clarify: is that a representation of a page with crop marks, or a paragraph with an unusual "frame" within the page boundaries?

Comment: Tht's been done...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Update

Now that the powerful [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) packages are around, this is an easy task:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{tcboppbox}[1][]{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  overlay first={
    \draw[#1] ([yshift=10pt]frame.north east) -- ++(0,-1cm);
    \draw[#1] ([xshift=10pt]frame.north east) -- ++(-1cm,0pt);
  },
  overlay last={
    \draw[#1] ([yshift=-10pt]frame.south west) -- ++(0,1cm);
    \draw[#1] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west) -- ++(1cm,0pt);
  },
  overlay unbroken={
    \draw[#1] ([yshift=10pt]frame.north east) -- ++(0,-1cm);
    \draw[#1] ([xshift=10pt]frame.north east) -- ++(-1cm,0pt);
    \draw[#1] ([yshift=-10pt]frame.south west) -- ++(0,1cm);
    \draw[#1] ([xshift=-10pt]frame.south west) -- ++(1cm,0pt);
  },
  colback=white,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcboppbox}
\lipsum[4] 
\end{tcboppbox}
\begin{tcboppbox}[line width=5pt,color=green!50!black]
\lipsum[4] 
\end{tcboppbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Initial version

You can define your own environment to add the frame; you can do something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate text for the example

\newenvironment{MyFrame}
  {\par\hfill\rlap{\kern-0.5cm\rule{1cm}{0.4pt}\kern-0.2cm\rule[-0.8cm]{0.4pt}{1cm}}%
    \vskip-\baselineskip}
  {\par\kern-0.5cm\hskip-0.9cm\rule{0.4pt}{1cm}\kern-0.2cm\rule[0.2cm]{1cm}{0.4pt}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{MyFrame}
\lipsum*[1]
\end{MyFrame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the help of the `xparse` package is easy to define a more sophisticated version of the `MyFrame` environment (this idea was suggested by Werner in a comment); in the following example, the new environment will have six optional arguments; the syntax is

```
\begin{MyFrame}[<length>][<rule thick.>][<hor. sep.>][<color>][<factor>][<vert. sep.>]
<contents>
\end{MyFrame}
```

where `<length>` controls the length of the rules used (default=`1cm`), `<rule thick.>` controls the "thickness" of the rules (defualt=`0.4pt`), `<hor. sep.>` controls the horizontal distance between the rules and the text (default=`0.8cm`), `<color>` allows you to select, with the help of the `xcolor` package, the color for the rules (default=`black`), `<factor>` is a number controlling the point of intersection of each pair of rules used for the frame (default=`3`), and `<ver. sep.>` controls the vertical distance between the rules and the text (default=`2ex`). Play with the values and you'll get some interesting frames. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\Text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra
metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.}% just to generate text for the example

\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{MyFrame}{O{1cm}O{0.4pt}O{0.8cm}O{black}O{3}O{2ex}}
  {\par\hfill\rlap{%
      \bgroup\color{#4}%
      \hskip-\dimexpr#1-#3\relax\rule{#1}{#2}%
      \hskip-\dimexpr#1/#5\relax\rule[-\dimexpr#1-\dimexpr#1/#5\relax]{#2}{#1}%
      \egroup
    }%
   \vskip-\dimexpr#1/#5+\dimexpr#1/#5-#6\relax%
  }
  {\par\nobreak\offinterlineskip\vskip-\dimexpr#1/#5+\dimexpr#1/#5-#6\relax\noindent%
      \hskip-#3\bgroup\color{#4}%
      \rule{#1}{#2}\hskip-\dimexpr#1-\dimexpr#1/#5-#2\relax%
      \rule[-\dimexpr#1/#5-#2\relax]{#2}{#1}\egroup\par
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{MyFrame}
\Text
\end{MyFrame}

\begin{MyFrame}[3cm][4pt][1.5cm][red!60]
\Text
\end{MyFrame}

\begin{MyFrame}[1.5cm][2pt][1.3cm][blue][2][8ex]
\Text
\end{MyFrame}

\begin{MyFrame}[1cm][7pt][0.6cm][olive!60][4][0ex]
\Text
\end{MyFrame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As requested in one comment, here's the definition of the `\MyFrame` environment (with the same six optional arguments) required for producing a four-corner version of the frame:

```
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{MyFrame}{O{1cm}O{0.4pt}O{0.8cm}O{black}O{3}O{2ex}}
  {\par\noindent\hskip-#3\bgroup\color{#4}%
      \rule{#1}{#2}\hskip-\dimexpr#1-\dimexpr#1/#5-#2\relax%
      \rule[-\dimexpr#1-\dimexpr#1/#5\relax]{#2}{#1}\egroup
      \hfill\rlap{%
        \bgroup\color{#4}%
        \hskip-\dimexpr#1-#3\relax\rule{#1}{#2}%
        \hskip-\dimexpr#1/#5\relax\rule[-\dimexpr#1-\dimexpr#1/#5\relax]{#2}{#1}%
        \egroup
    }%
   \vskip-\dimexpr#1/#5+\dimexpr#1/#5-#6\relax%
  }
  {\par\nobreak\offinterlineskip\vskip-\dimexpr#1/#5+\dimexpr#1/#5-#6\relax\noindent%
      \hskip-#3\bgroup\color{#4}%
      \rule{#1}{#2}\hskip-\dimexpr#1-\dimexpr#1/#5-#2\relax%
      \rule[-\dimexpr#1/#5-#2\relax]{#2}{#1}\egroup
      \hfill\rlap{%
        \bgroup\color{#4}%
        \hskip-\dimexpr#1-#3\relax\rule{#1}{#2}%
        \hskip-\dimexpr#1/#5\relax\rule[-\dimexpr#1/#5-#2\relax]{#2}{#1}%
        \egroup
    }%
  \par
}
```

And the following code (same preamble as before)

```
\begin{MyFrame}
\Text
\end{MyFrame}\vskip\baselineskip

\begin{MyFrame}[1.5cm][3pt][1cm][red!60][4][5.5ex]
\Text
\end{MyFrame}\vskip\baselineskip

\begin{MyFrame}[1cm][7pt][0.6cm][olive!60][4][0ex]
\Text
\end{MyFrame}
```

now produces the following result:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make `MyFrame` take arguments so that you can modify (say) the distance outside the margin, the width of the rule, and the length of the rule? Something to the effect of `\begin{MyFrame}[<width>][<thickness>][<length>]`, all being optional with some default value as in your example.

Comment: @Werner: yes, or course; see my updated answer. Now you can control the distance outside the margin, the width of the rules, their length, and three more attributes. Thanks for suggesting this improvement.

Comment: That's awesome! I guess one final miracle would be if these paragraph decorations would not influence `\parskip`, thereby leaving the natural gap between paragraphs.

Comment: That's wonderfull ! Thanks a lot Gonzalo.  
 
One last question, what are the changes to make so as to have a four corners version ?

Comment: @projetmbc: see my updated answer.

Comment: @Werner: it could be done, but then some of the decorations would result ambiguous, or even (as in the olive decoration of my examples) overlap the previous/following text, producing an undesired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update with the "four corners" option !

Comment: How can you change the corners to `\ulcorner`, `\urcorner`, `\llcorner`, `\lrcorner`? I don't want to make a new question as I believe it might be classified as a possible duplicate.

Comment: I was thinking: `\newenvironment{MyFrame}
  {\par \rlap{$\ulcorner$}\hfill\rlap{$\urcorner$}
    \vskip-\baselineskip}
  {\par\llap{$\llcorner$}\hfill\rlap{$\lrcorner$}\par}` but this does not look right.

Comment: @azetina in some hours (almost bed time for me) I will look at your request and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

Try my new [crbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/crbox) package:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{crbox}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}
\begin{document}
\crbox{\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy tex
}}

\bigskip
\crbox[curved]{\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy tex
}}

\bigskip
\crbox[hollowcurved]{\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy tex
}}
\end{document}
```

and this is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I'm no searching for that kind of outputs.

Comment: But I'm searching for exactly this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using [the `crop` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/crop):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4,center]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\crop[cross,noinfo]

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

For the case where you only want specific marks to be shown, you can use the `\cropdef` command to disable the unwanted marks.

---

And with [the `geometry` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showcrop,
papersize={8.5in,11.0in},
layoutsize={6.5in,9.0in},layoutoffset=1.0in
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Note that you need to specify the layout size smaller than paper size to see the crop marks.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. I have been searching for one solution working with pargraphs.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccp{10pt}cp{10pt}cc}
 & \vline & & & & & \\
\cline{1-3}
 & \vline & & & & & \\
 & \vline & & Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla & & & \\
 & \vline & & Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla & & & \\
 & & & Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla & & & \\
 & & & Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla & & & \\
 & & & Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla & & & \\
 & & & Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla & & \vline & \\
 & & & Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla & & \vline & \\
 & & & & & \vline & \\
\cline{5-7}
 & & & & & \vline & \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

But @Gonzalo Medina's answer is much more elegant.

[image]